# May I submit an input method which uses Quartz Event to Mac app store?

Tags: macos, appstore-approval

My input method program does mouse / keyboard hooking, it does not predict text like usual Mac's input methods.

It is not integrated into Language & Text system preferences panel.

It requires "Enable access for assistive devices".

It smiliars to a built in input method. (It offers many more functions, productivity)

It continues running in background after closing its windows. It leaves an icon in status menu. It will quit if user selects "Exit" menu item.